# Python Selenium can't scrape Newly loaded Sources using scroll function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape links from google search using selenium and i wrote the following code to do that

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(673, 720)

query = "jobs for back-end dev"

driver.get(f"https://google.com/search?q={query}")

# To scrape links
elems = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//a[@jsname='UWckNb']")
    for elem in elems:
        link = elem.get_attribute("href")
        if "https://www.google.com" not in link:
            print(link)
```

The following code works fine to scrape the currently loaded page but i want to keep scraping links. so i tried to add `scroll` function to get more link

```
#scroll
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

# To scrape links
elems = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//a[@jsname='UWckNb']")
    for elem in elems:
        link = elem.get_attribute("href")
        if "https://www.google.com" not in link:
            print(link)
```

output: `give me the same links as above code without the newly added sources`

Comment: It is giving new links but it will also give old links. You can use if condition to filter old links.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it was giving me old links only though i solved the problem by waiting until the site loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a silly error in my code that i was not waiting for the site to load before scraping using `time` to wait until the site loads properly fixed my issue

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(673, 720)

query = "jobs for back-end dev"

driver.get(f"https://google.com/search?q={query}")

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

time.sleep(5) # <- change here (waiting for site to load before scraping)

# To scrape links
elems = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//a[@jsname='UWckNb']")
    for elem in elems:
        link = elem.get_attribute("href")
        if "https://www.google.com" not in link:
            print(link)
```